# how to enable lifetime active status for X-CSRF-TOKEN

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4. In config/session.php lifetime for a session more than 100 hours but when i do ajax request i get this error

```
1) TokenMismatchException
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php line 53
```

I have added below in header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

and

using javascript

```
var token =  $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
```

to get token.

I don't want token to expire ever.

Ajax code as requested

```
var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: path + '/load_free_data',
        data: 'selected_day=' + day +'&opt=' + opt  + '&_token=' + token , 
        beforeSend : function()
        {  
             $('.white-overlay').show();
        },
        success: function(e)
         {

             data = e.data;

         }
     });
```

Comment: Can you post your full ajax call code ?

Comment: Please see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include this in html header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then after including jquery script cdn include, or after all includes,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Then you can use your ajax call and it should work.

Comment: i did exactly same thing and v v strange that token expired in few seconds and still see same error

Comment: what do you mean expired? can you update your answer with your whole blade template?

Comment: sorry i mean after 5 - 10 seconds when i tried same ajax call i saw this error.(1/1) TokenMismatchException
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 148

Comment: have you deleted '&_token=' + token ,  from data attribute in your ajax call?

Comment: Yes sir. it is removed from params

Comment: I have to see the blade view. because it should be working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185796/discussion-between-bilal-rabbi-and-giorgi-lagidze).